# What is the difference between json.dumps/loads and tornado.escape.json_encode/json_decode?

Tags: python, tornado

It seems they are behaving exactly the same way.

```
>>> data
[('a', 'b'), {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, ['a', 'b'], 'a', 'b']
>>> json.dumps(data)
'[["a", "b"], {"a": 1, "b": 2}, ["a", "b"], "a", "b"]'
>>> tornado.escape.json_encode(data)
'[["a", "b"], {"a": 1, "b": 2}, ["a", "b"], "a", "b"]'
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(data))
[[u'a', u'b'], {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}, [u'a', u'b'], u'a', u'b']
>>> tornado.escape.json_decode(json.dumps(data))
[[u'a', u'b'], {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}, [u'a', u'b'], u'a', u'b']
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes it's useful to read [the source code](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/escape.py):

```
def json_encode(value):
    return json.dumps(value).replace("</", "<\\/")

def json_decode(value):
    return json.loads(to_basestring(value))

def to_basestring(value):
    if isinstance(value, _BASESTRING_TYPES):
        return value
    assert isinstance(value, bytes_type)
    return value.decode("utf-8")
```

`to_basestring` is mostly needed for python 3.x to ensure the `value` has type `str`, not `bytes`, because `json.loads` can't deal with the latter.